# Magento 2.2 Make custom tab disappear when specific attribute is not set

Tags: module, magento2.2, design

I created a custom product tab that I want to use for a specific attribute set. For that attribute set I have created a number of specific attributes.

The custom product tab works nice. However it is visible for every product, which is not wanted. How could I make sure that the tab is only visible for a specific attribute set (or product attributes for that matter).

My code:

1. `app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php`

   ```
   <?php

   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
       'Mark_Eopyy',
       __DIR__
   );
   ```
2. `app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="Mark_Eopyy" setup_version="1.0.0">

       <sequence>
           <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
       </sequence>


       </module>
   </config>
   ```
3. `app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>      
           <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">         

              <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="Mark_Eopyy::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                   <arguments>
                       <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">ΕΟΠΥΥ</argument>
                   </arguments>
               </block>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
4. `app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details/custom_tab.phtml`

   ```
   <?php
   $product = $block->getProduct();
   ?>
   <h1 style="color: #1979c3"><?php echo $product->getData('product_attribute'); ?></h1>
   ```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by wrapping the `html` part of the template file in a PHP `if` statement.

Code:

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if( $product->getData('product_attribute') ): ?>
<h1 style="color: #1979c3"><?php echo $product->getData('product_attribute'); ?></h1>


<?php endif; ?>
```

However I don't tick this as solved yet, in case someone points to a more elegant solution.